# How to combine code so that I can select either value and have it output the new value. Need to be able to insert new rows when required

Tags: excel, vba

This is only a sample of 3 names in a column that I use to add number values. There are 100 in total. Problem is when I insert another row all of the specific row number linked to the name change and the function no longer works for that name. Hard to explain

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
      
    'PENSACOLA
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target.Address = Range("b25").Address Then
        Range("c25") = Range("c25") + Range("b25")
    End If
    If Target.Address = Range("b25").Address Then
        Range("b25").Copy Range("d25")
        Range("b25").ClearContents
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
    'OMAHA(U.S.A.)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target.Address = Range("b27").Address Then
        Range("c27") = Range("c27") + Range("b27")
    End If
    If Target.Address = Range("b27").Address Then
        Range("b27").Copy Range("d27")
        Range("b27").ClearContents
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
    'OKHOTNIK
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target.Address = Range("b32").Address Then
        Range("c32") = Range("c32") + Range("b32")
    End If
    If Target.Address = Range("b32").Address Then
        Range("b32").Copy Range("d32")
        Range("b32").ClearContents
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

[Entering credits for each ship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuOiO.jpg)

Comment: When you say "name" what are you talking about?  I am afraid that you (only) used a word able to be the key of the problem... I mean **Name the respective ranges** in an eloquent way and then use these names. Select one such a cell and write a name, let us say, "Cell1" in the `Name box` (the one to the left of formula bar), then press Enter.

Comment: I hope you understood what I suggested above... Then use `If Target.Address = ActiveWorkbook.Names("Cell1").RefersToRange.Address Then`, instead of `If Target.Address = Range("b25").Address Then`... `Named` ranges updates their address if you insert/delete rows.

Comment: A screenshot of your sheet would help a lot here.

Comment: FYI your logic is repeated over and over - once you determine if the `Target` cell is one you're interested in, all other steps are the same and you can just use `Target` and `Target.Offset()` to reference the cells you need to work with.

Comment: https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/variables.html

Comment: Added Pic. The code allows me to enter credits earned in column B beside each ship name. It then adds the current Total column C and copies the entered amount in column D as a reminder. The problem I have is when I insert a new Row to allow another ship it changes the row number to the current ship name then my code is off by how many rows I insert. I then have to change all of the rows numbers. Is there a way so that I can select any ship enter it's credits earned and no matter what row the ship is in it will do the same thing.  I would be happy to send entire worksheet is that's allowed. Tnx

Comment: My apologies I am real new with respect to VBA in Excel and also this site. I am very thankful for any help. Thank you